# Python Regular Expression help. Combinations

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read from a text file and create a list of seed words that begin a sentence and a second list containing all adjacent words excluding the seed words.

The problem I'm encountering is that words containing an apostrophe get split after the apostrophe and the rest of the word omitted. How would you keep them as they appear in the file?

**Text contained in file:**

```
This doesn't seem to work. Is findall or sub the correct approach? Or neither?
```

CODE:

```
my_string = open('sample.txt', 'r').read()

starter = list(set(re.findall(r"(?<![a-z]\s)[A-Z]\w+", my_string)))
adjacent = re.findall(r"(?<!(?<![a-z]\s))\w+", my_string) 

print(my_string)
```

RESULT:

```
['doesn', 'seem', 'to', 'work', 'sub', 'or', 'findall', 'the', 'correct', 'approach', 'neither']
```

Comment: What is the input and what do you expect as correct output?

Comment: Sorry the text contained in the file is above the code snippet. I'm expecting the first element of the list to be "doesn't"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier with two regex's:

```
import re

txt="""\
This doesn't seem to work. Is findall or sub the correct approach? Or neither? Isn't it grand?
"""

first_words=set(re.findall(r'(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(\b[a-zA-Z\']+)', txt))

rest={word for word in re.findall(r'(\b[a-zA-Z\']+)', txt) if word not in first_words}

print first_words
# set(['This', 'Is', 'Or', "Isn't"])
print rest
# set(["doesn't", 'sub', 'grand', 'the', 'work', 'it', 'findall', 'to', 'neither', 'correct', 'seem', 'approach', 'or'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm encountering is that words containing an apostrophe get split after the apostrophe and the rest of the word omitted.

The **slash-w-plus** isn't your friend.  It is a short-cut for alphabetic characters, numbers, and underscores.  It does not include hyphens or apostrophes.

Use a character range instead.  That way you can include apostrophes and exclude numbers and underscores:

```
r"[A-Za-z\']+"           # works better than \w+
```